# MongoDB Returning One Nested Document from a Result

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a MongoDB collection called "ballots" and it looks like this:

```
{
  "_id" : "msw9ofwQSj58qiPvY",
  "ballotName" : "This is the ballot name",
  "votes" : [
    { "unitNumber" : "30", "voteResult" : "No", "voteDate" : ISODate("2015-02-24T05:03:22.937Z") },
    { "unitNumber" : "30", "voteResult" : "Yes", "voteDate" : ISODate("2015-02-24T05:20:02.479Z") }
  ]
}
```

I want to see only the LATEST "votes.voteResult" for this _id and by unitNumber:30.  I try:

```
db.ballots.find(
  { $and: [
    {_id: 'msw9ofwQSj58qiPvY'},
    {'votes.unitNumber': '30'}
  ] },
  {'votes.voteResult': 1, 'votes.voteDate': 1, _id: 0} )
```

Results:

```
{
  "votes" : [
    {
      "voteResult": "No",
      "voteDate" : ISODate("2015-02-24T05:03:22.937Z")
    },
    {
      "voteResult": "Yes",
      "voteDate" : ISODate("2015-02-24T05:20:02.479Z")
    }
  ]
}
```

Looks good, however I only want ONE "voteResult" to return.  I only want the latest one.  I cannot seem to figure out how to get one of the nested result sets, AND ensure it is the most recent one.  If it's any help, I am using Meteor/javascript which perhaps can handle the coding logic of this, but hoping a simple MongoDB query can just give me the result.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How many votes are you expecting in a ballot .. and how would you find the "latest" one (by voteDate?). Are you relying on Minimongo, or could you install an additional package to access the server-side aggregation features (eg: [meteor-aggregate](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-aggregate/)) ?

Comment: Total number of votes would be about 30-100 per ballot document in Mongo. Meteor uses miniMongo which I use for dev and testing, and yes, I can use meteor-aggregate. Reading about it now...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sort` and `limit` for these things:

```
db.ballots.find(
  { $and: [
    {_id: 'msw9ofwQSj58qiPvY'},
    {'votes.unitNumber': '30'},
  ] },
  {'votes.voteResult': 1, 'votes.voteDate': 1, _id: 0} 
).sort({'votes.voteDate':-1).limit(1);
```

You get both back, but if you sort them by voteDate and return the first one, you should have the one you want.

You might also be able to do it all server-side using `aggregate` instead of `find`:

```
db.ballots.aggregate( 
  {$match : 
    {$and: [
      {_id: 'msw9ofwQSj58qiPvY'},
      {'votes.unitNumber': '30'},
    ]}
  },
  {$unwind: "$votes"},
  {$sort: {'votes.voteDate': -1}},
  {$limit: 1},
  {$project: {'votes.voteResult': 1, 'votes.voteDate': 1, _id: 0}}
);
```

Comment: Unless Minimongo is doing something different from the MongoDB server API (which is possible), the `sort` and `limit` cursor options normally only apply at the document level. This might be fine to sort multiple documents with votes, but won't return the expected result from an embedded array (as in the current example document in the question). Similarly, to get the expected result in server-side aggregation you need to first `$unwind` the embedded array and then `$sort` and `$group` in order to get a single "latest" match per document.

Comment: You are correct. I've edited the answer to note this.